# Determinant of a block matrix with dissimilar elements

Tags: matrices, determinants, vector-spaces

I am looking for an expression that convert calculation of given quadratic form into determinant of some block matrix. I see this in that form (that may be incorrect):

$x^T A x = \begin{vmatrix} x^T  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x \end{vmatrix}$

To clarify. The above matrix is a block matrix with “additional” block entries on the diagonal of the matrix. There are two 3-dimensional vectors $x$ and a matrix $A$ of size $3\times3$.

My first port of call was the application of the determinant formula for block matrices, given in the next link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Firstly, I did not find the application of the above formulas to the structure with which I am dealing, and secondly, the standard det commands in Mathkad and Matlab do not work with such structures. I was wondering if there was an article among mathematicians or a well-known formula that would facilitate this task.

The task for me now is to somehow find an expression for the determinant, so that the solution to the problem consists of at least a combination of “det” commands Mathkad and Matlab.

Comment: I don't get at all that formula. $x^T A x$ surely isn't equal to $\begin{vmatrix} x^T  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x \end{vmatrix}$. Actually the RHS is zero, because the matrix is upper triangular with zeros on its diagonal.

Comment: This is a conditional entry form. Made for illustration purposes only. If we assume that $a = x$, $b = A$, $c = x^T$, then the determinant is equal to $a b c$. I want to understand if it is possible to turn the calculation of the quadratic form into the calculation of the determinant of some block  matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard for me to understand what you are asking, but maybe this answers your question. One has
$$
-x^TAx = M / A^{-1},
$$
where
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}A^{-1} & x\\ x^T & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and the symbol $/$ denotes the [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=Schur%20complement).

One has
$$
\det(M / A^{-1}) = \det(M) / \det(A^{-1}) = \det(M)\det(A),
$$
so you get
$$
x^TAx = -\det(M)\det(A).
$$

Side note: if your goal is actually computing things numerically, then using determinants is usually considered a bad idea. The good thing about determinants is that they give you closed forms of stuff, but when it comes to scientific computing you are almost always better off without using them.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like that. I want to clarify - how is the determinant of the $M$ calculated, how is the determinant of a block matrix?

Comment: @dtn A block matrix is just a matrix that is obtained by stacking the corresponding blocks. Its determinant does not have a particular definition, it is just the 'usual' determinant of a matrix.

Comment: I already checked this with calculations. It really is. No special formulas are needed to calculate the determinants. In general, you helped me by suggesting what the Shur complement is. Thank you very much!

Comment: Always happy to help!